# Efficiently converting a Series of dictionaries to a DataFrame

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a large (ish) `Series` of dictionaries that I'd like "flatten". In order to test / reproduce my problem I have created a `Series` with a similar structure:

```
>>> my_series = pd.Series([{'A': [1], 'B' : []}, {'A' : [1, 2], 'B' : [3, 4]}])
>>> my_series
0           {u'A': [1], u'B': []}
1    {u'A': [1, 2], u'B': [3, 4]}
dtype: object
```

The next step is converting it to a 'DataFrame' with a hierarchical index. I have found a way that works functionally:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(row, orient='index').stack() for row in my_series)
     A         B     
     0    1    0    1
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

This gives me what I want, but on my actual dataset it is prohibitively slow, taking around 60 seconds for 30,000 rows with 0-4 elements in each of the lists, and using around 8G of RAM.

I have tried using a parallel `map` operation with the `multiprocessing` module to speed things up, but thought I'd ask here to see if there was a better way.

Can I achieve the same outcome as above in a more reasonable time?

Comment: @Kasramvd I'm not sure how it was constructed, but I will look into this - thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame` constructor, but first convert `Series` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and then to `list`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(my_series.values.tolist())
print (a)
        A       B
0     [1]      []
1  [1, 2]  [3, 4]
```

Then for flatennig is possible use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `list comprehension`:

```
b = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a[x].values.tolist()) for x in a.columns], axis=1,keys=a.columns)
print (b)
   A         B     
   0    1    0    1
0  1  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

If convert to numpy array is is faster:

```
In [93]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(list(my_series))
1000 loops, best of 3: 550 µs per loop

In [94]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(my_series.values.tolist())
1000 loops, best of 3: 516 µs per loop
```

Comment: I don't really understand why but this trick reduced the time from minutes to less than a second. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, since you have your dictionaries in a pandas-based data structure you might be able to create a `DataFrame` instead of a series.

Secondly `DataFrame` can accept a list of dictionaries and construct the expected result for you. So, if you don't have the control over the construction of the series in the first place, you can just convert the series to list and pass it to `DataFrame`:

```
In [10]: pd.DataFrame(list(my_series))
Out[10]: 
        A       B
0     [1]      []
1  [1, 2]  [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setup**

```
my_series = pd.Series([{'A': [1], 'B' : []}, {'A' : [1, 2], 'B' : [3, 4]}])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(s.tolist())
```

**Solution**

Ok, got a faster solution working.

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],[0,1]])

pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(df.values.flatten().tolist()).values.reshape(2,-1), columns=idx)

Out[1051]: 
     A         B     
     0    1    0    1
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

**Old Solution**

```
#Convert list elements to columns
df_A = df.A.apply(pd.Series).stack().unstack()
df_B = df.B.apply(pd.Series).stack().unstack()
#rename columns
df_A.columns = ['A_' + str(e) for e in df_A.columns]
df_B.columns = ['B_' + str(e) for e in df_B.columns]
#combine two dataframes
pd.concat([df_A,df_B],axis=1)

Out[973]: 
   A_0  A_1  B_0  B_1
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

**Test**

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(df.values.flatten().tolist()).values.reshape(2,-1), columns=idx)
1000 loops, best of 3: 378 µs per loop

%timeit pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[x].values.tolist()) for x in df.columns], axis=1,keys=df.columns)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. Just came up with a faster solution

Comment: Yes, but there are always `2` columns? Also OP wants MultiIndex in columns, what do you think?

Comment: For more than 2 columns, changing reshape() should work. Let me have a look at Multiindex

Comment: Multiindex added.